# Specify qualifier already but get NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring

Newbie to `Spring` learing about `dependence injection` now.
I already know that `Qualifier` annnotation is used to distinguish difference dependencies.But following code doesn't work.

```
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("taylor")
    public CDPlayer cheapCDPlayer(CompactDisc cd){
        return new CheapCDPlayer(cd);
    }
```

Here `CompactDisc` is an interface implemented by two class `SgtPeppers` and `Taylor`. `Taylor` is annotated with qualifier `taylor`,which I want to be injected into this method.But I still get `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException`. How to fix it? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think this way you are marking cheapCDPlayer with "taylor". Try putting @Qualifier("taylor") before cd argument: ... (@Qualifier("taylor") CompactDisc cd) {...}

Comment: @rebelizant  yeah, this is exactly the case.At first,I thought the qualifier cannot be used for method params.

Answer (score 1):

`@Configuration` Beans can, as in your example, reference existing beans in the method signature.
You could add the `@Qualifier` to the method signature like this

```
@Bean
public CDPlayer cheapCDPlayer( @Qualifier("taylor") CompactDisc cd){
        return new CheapCDPlayer(cd);
}
```

for solving your problem

Comment: I gave this a little consideration but I thought this is not an annotation for method parameters.It turns out I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you can use @Resource to choose your impl

```
@Resource(name="taylor")
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't sure if my answer helps for this question, but if somebody is desperately looking for a right "qualifier-solution", but can't solve his problem with any qualifier it could be a dependency collision problem. Exclusion of "wrong" dependency (from pom.xml) could help. (Sometimes it could be tricky. One time I had such a "wrong" dependency in two projects. One project was dependent on another. The dependency should only be removed from the "right" project. After that it worked.)

Answer (score -1):

Since you want to inject "Taylor" bean in this method use `@Autowired`instead of`@Qualifier("taylor")`